# next instance of

Tags: javascript, jquery

trying to get the next matching element in a list;

```
var newScrollX = $('#projectImages li').next(".instOf"+myNo);
```

the above works but i don't want it to go back to earlier instances in the list so;

```
var newScrollX = $('#projectImages li').next(".instOf"+myNo+":gt("+cIm+")");
```

but that doesn't work. Any ideas?

list is like this;

```
<li id="im1" class="projIm instOf1" style="opacity: 1; left: 202px;"></li>
<li id="im2" class="projIm instOf2" style="opacity: 1; left: 1413px;"></li>
<li id="im3" class="projIm instOf3" style="opacity: 1; left: 2624px;"></li>
<li id="im4" class="projIm instOf1" style="opacity: 1; left: 3620px;"></li>
<li id="im5" class="projIm instOf2" style="opacity: 1; left: 4831px;"></li>
<li id="im6" class="projIm instOf3" style="opacity: 1; left: 6042px;"></li>
<li id="im7" class="projIm instOf1" style="opacity: 1; left: 7038px;"></li>
<li id="im8" class="projIm instOf2" style="opacity: 1; left: 8249px;"></li>
<li id="im9" class="projIm **instOf3**" style="opacity: 1; left: 9460px;"></li>
<li id="im10" class="projIm instOf1" style="opacity: 1; left: 10456px;"></li>
<li id="im11" class="projIm instOf2" style="opacity: 1; left: 11667px;"></li>
<li id="im12" class="projIm instOf3" style="opacity: 1; left: 12878px;"></li>
```

so if you are on #im7, and you want the next instance of **instOf3** it should go to #im9 and not back which it does sometimes now.

So i was thinking if i added a gt(7) it would only go forward but i get an error...

Comment: This *looks* like Javascript using the jQuery library. You should probably tag it as such so people understand the context.

Comment: How does the list look like and what values do the variables have?

Comment: Please show us the html code for the list you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this... I also posted a demo in [this pastebin](http://pastebin.me/3aafa9c0878c82c78fa037ec34bf847b).

```
var newScrollX = $(this).nextAll(".instOf"+myNo+":first");
```

Assuming that `$(this)` is the currently selected object.

---

Update:

Please forgive me for taking liberties and cleaning up your code, my OCD compelled me to do it! Here are a few notes:

- I chained multiple functions and used `.end()` ([link](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/end)) as needed.
- There is no need to use `eval()` in the code.
- I replaced the `.prevAll().length` portion of the code, since the ID contains the current length.

  ```
  .substring(2,newScrollX.length); // im4 -> 4
  ```
- I combined the scrolling update into one function that both the links and image click use.
- I removed all comments and unused
  variables. Sorry if I removed
  something else you were working on.
- The current image display was modified. I used the current ID and a [modulus operator](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_operators.asp) to calculate the image number - it's less coding :P

  ```
  cImDis = ((cIm-1) % totIm) + 1;
  ```

Script

```
    var edge, marginLeft;
    var cIm = 1; // make this global

$(document).ready(function(){
    edge = $("#navDiv").offset();
    marginLeft = edge.left;
    $('#projectImages')
        .css("background-position",marginLeft+"px 10px")
        .children("li").each(function(i){
            $(this).css('opacity', 0.0);
        })

    $("div.personInfo")
        .children(".toShow").hide().end()
        .each(function(i){
            $(this).click(function(){
                var tgt = $("#xxx"+(i+1));
                if($("#xxx"+(i+1)).is(":visible")){
                    $("#xxx"+(i+1)).slideUp(150);
                } else {
                    $("#xxx"+(i+1)).slideDown(200);
                }
            });
        });
})

$(window).resize(function(){
    edge = $("#navDiv").offset();
    marginLeft = edge.left;
})

$(window).load(function(){
    cIm =1;
    var cImDis =1;
    var totIm = parseInt($("#totIm").text(),10);
    var totX = 0;
    edge = $("#navDiv").offset();
    marginLeft = edge.left;
    var imageIcons="";

    $('#projectImages')
        .css("background-position","-1000px 20px")
        .children("li:eq(0)").animate({ 
            opacity: 1.0
        }, 400 ).end()
        .children("li").each(function(i){

            if(i>0){
                totX = 0;
                $(this).parent("ul").children("li:lt("+i+")").each(function(){
                    totX += $(this).width();
                });
                $(this).css("left",(totX+marginLeft)+"px");
                totX += $(this).width();
                $(this).animate({
                    opacity: 1.0
                }, 400 );
            } else {
                $(this).css("left",marginLeft+"px");
            }
            imageIcons +="<a class=\"scrollTo\" href=\"#\" rel='im"+(i+1)+"'> • </a>";
        });

        $("#imageIcons").html(imageIcons);
        $("#imageIcons a:eq(0)").addClass("activeImage");
        $("h3.phil:eq(0)").children('a').addClass("activeText");

        $("a.scrollToText").click(function(){
            cImDis = $(this).attr("rel");
            var newScrollX = $('#im'+cIm).nextAll(".instOf" + cImDis + ":first").attr('id');
            cIm = parseInt(newScrollX.substring(2,newScrollX.length),10);
            nextIm();
            return false;
        })

        $("#projectImages li img").click(function(){
            cIm++;
            cImDis = ((cIm-1) % totIm) + 1; // find remainder
            nextIm();
            return false;
        })

        function nextIm(){
            var newScrollX = $("#im"+cIm);
            var posX = parseInt(newScrollX.css("left"),10);
            $('#projectImages').scrollTo((posX-marginLeft)+"px", 350, updateDisplay());
            $("#feedback").prepend("<li>(cim:"+cIm+") (cimDis:"+cImDis+")</li>");
        }

        function updateDisplay(){
            $("#cIm").text(cImDis);
            $(".activeText").each(function(){
                $(this).removeClass("activeText");
            });
            $("h3.phil:eq("+(cImDis-1)+")").children('a').addClass("activeText");
        }
});
```

Comment: mmm - can't seem to get this working - what if $(this) isn't the currently select object?! But;

    var current = $('#projectImages').children('li:eq('+(cIm-1)+')');
    var newScrollX = current.nextAll(".instOf"+myNo+":first");
// cIm-1 is current item
// http://dmfk.modernactivity.co.uk/about/people
   
though this doesn't work either... thanks for the pointers!

Comment: that worked a treat! And tha end() will come in pretty handy. Thanks very much for the help fudgey and sorry it took so long to check it.

D.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might want to refer to list elements by their index... although the question isn't very easy to understand.

Have a look at [:eq](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/eq) and [index()](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/index)

I get the feeling some maths and these bad boys might get you where you need to go.